# Is there a way to get USB link quality information?

Tags: usb

I am debugging a USB connection on a Raspberry Pi - devices are being dropped and reset by the host or by USB hubs in the tree.

The devices are connected with non-USB-standard wiring (don't ask why, long story) and we are fairly sure that there are signal integrity issues.

Is there a way to get USB "link quality" information? Things like number of CRC errors, failed bus turnarounds, basically any low-level data about the bus like that. Anything that might help quantify the issue.

The Pi is running a standard raspbian distro and I have SSH access.

Answer (score 0):

One possible tool is [usbmon](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt); it traces I/O on the USB bus.